# MySQL / PHP - Multi tier category structure

Tags: php, mysql, orm, yii2, hierarchical-data

I'm building a website that contains a product database. Each product belongs to a category. The structure of categories is multi-tiered and can contain any number of tiers, for example:

- `Electronics` > `Games Consoles` > `Xbox` > `Xbox One` > `Games` > `etc..`
- `Fashion` > `Mens` > `Shirts` > `Long Sleeved`

I always assign the product to the "last" category in the tier.

Here is the structure of my category table:

```
id       name            parent_id
================================
1        Fashion         NULL
2        Mens            1
3        Shirts          2
4        Long Sleeved    3
5        Short Sleeved   3
```

I'm using Yii2 as my application framework, but the same concepts should apply to most MVC Frameworks, or at least those that implement an ORM like ActiveRecord.

What I want to do is:

1. For any category level, get the "master" parent. I.e. for `Shirts` it would be `Fashion`
2. For any category level, get all "last" level categories in the tier. I.e. for `Mens` it would be `Long Sleeved` and `Short Sleeved`.
3. (more advanced) For any category level, find out the number of children / parents it has.

I have the following default relations in my model:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id']);
}

public function getParent()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Category::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id']);
}
```

The following is a function I have created which outputs the "tree" for any given category:

```
public function getParentTree()
{
    $array = [];

    // $this->parent refers to the 'getParent()' relation above
    if(!empty($this->parent))
    {
        $array[] = $this->parent->name;

        if(!empty($this->parent->parent))
            $array[] = $this->parent->parent->name;

                if(!empty($this->parent->parent->parent))
                    $array[] = $this->parent->parent->parent->name;
    }
    else
        $array[] = "(none)";

    $output = implode(" --> ", array_reverse($array));

    return $output;
}
```

But there is a lot of repetition here and it looks ugly. But it is also leading me to be believe perhaps I have taken the wrong approach and need to restructure the database itself?

Comment: You're on the right track with `parent_id`, you could probably find a tree-builder online, or you can just make your function recursive. Ie, check if the current element has a parent, add the parent to the array and run the same function on the parent (this will iterate all the way up the tree).

Comment: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

Comment: parent_id is the ideal way to store your data in your category table but you will want to index the category paths to do what you are doing if you need to avoid recursion. You could store this information in Yii's cache, or, if you need the path index available in SQL queries, you can create a table that stores the category paths, updating this table as the tree structure changes.

Answer (score 0):

Bill I think I have resolved this issue in YII2 -> Models.

Below is my code.

```
public static function getSubCategories($parent_id = NULL, $level = 0)
{
    // Get the Category from table
    // Here you can use caching Yii::$app->cache->get to avoid multiple queries
    $categories = Category::find()->select(['id', 'parent_id', 'name'])->where(['parent_id' => $parent_id])->asArray()->all();

    // Logic of Nth level to return
    self::$max_down_level += 1;
    if($level != 0 && self::$max_down_level > $level) return $categories;

    // Now for each sub categories find and return chidren as Array
    foreach($categories as $key => $category)
    {
        $categories[$key]['children'] = self::getSubCategories($category['id'], $level);
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Also do not forget to declare `public static $max_down_level = 0;` variable in your model class. and now call the function like below.

1. To get all the children of Parent category `self::getSubCategories(NULL)`
2. To get all the children up to 2nd level `self::getSubCategories(NULL, 2)`

Same way above you can declare recursive function for getting parent Categories.

```
public static function getParentCategories($parent_id, $level = 0)
{
    // Get the Category from table
    // Here you can use caching Yii::$app->cache->get to avoid multiple queries
    $categories = Category::find()->select(['id', 'parent_id', 'name'])->where(['id' => $parent_id])->asArray()->all();

    // Logic of Nth level to return
    self::$max_up_level += 1;
    if($level != 0 && self::$max_up_level > $level) return $categories;

    foreach($categories as $key => $category)
    {
        $categories[$key]['parent'] = self::getParentCategories($category['parent_id'], $level);
    }

    return $categories;
}
```

Also do not forget to declare `public static $max_up_level = 0;` variable in your model class. and now call the function like below.

1. To get all the children of Parent category self::getParentCategories(16, 0)
2. To get all the children up to 2nd level self::getParentCategories(16, 2)

You can use your own class name instead of `self`

Hope this helps.